# Discord.js cannot read property id of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

so here's the thing. I've done a bot with discord.js, it was working well and then it crashed.

The reason I get is "guild.channels.set(channel.id, channel);
^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"

And this error seems to be in node_modules\discord.js\src\client\ClientDataManager.js:81

But I just don't know what to do, the bot can't log and I didn't change the main file so I don't really understand

Comment: Can you confirm that the `channel` variable is set properly?

Comment: It's in the newChannel() function of ClientDataManager but I don't know what it is used for ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like this error comes from the new "stage" channel type they recently added.
The error comes from the fact that it's not listed in the ClientDataManager newChannel() switch nor anywhere else as you would need to update Discord.js to add its support.

If you don't want to update Discord.js a temporary fix would be to add `if(channel != null)` line 81.

But your bot won't be able to handle the Stage channels, so the only solution would be to udpate Discord.js

Comment: Stumbled upon your answer on google, Your temporary fix worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I added a If in ClientDataManager.js to avoid this error, not quite sure if this was the way to fix that error but that seems to work so better than nothing I guess ...

If you have any other idea don't hesitate

Comment: I'd be better if you comment that under the respective question or append it to your question.

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because of the new feature discord added known as 'stage channels', the only fix to this is to update discord.js to the latest version. At the time of writing this I am running discord.js 12.5.3 and I am not facing that issue