# Discord bot failing to start - ClientDataManager.js cannot read property 'id' of undefined, Replit problem

Tags: javascript, discord.js

My code was all fine before this happened, but for some reason, it stopped working. And when I try to run the bot it sends an error.

Error:

```
DwaCraft SayBot Starting....
/home/runner/SayBot99109463/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/ClientDataManager.js:81
        guild.channels.set(channel.id, channel);
                                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at ClientDataManager.newChannel (/home/runner/SayBot99109463/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/ClientDataManager.js:81:36)
    at Guild.setup (/home/runner/SayBot99109463/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/Guild.js:307:68)
    at GuildCreateHandler.handle (/home/runner/SayBot99109463/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/handlers/GuildCreate.js:12:15)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (/home/runner/SayBot99109463/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/WebSocketPacketManager.js:108:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (/home/runner/SayBot99109463/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:336:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (/home/runner/SayBot99109463/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:299:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/runner/SayBot99109463/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at WebSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/home/runner/SayBot99109463/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:789:20)
    at Receiver.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at Receiver.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at Receiver.dataMessage (/home/runner/SayBot99109463/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:413:14)
    at Receiver.getData (/home/runner/SayBot99109463/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:352:17)
    at Receiver.startLoop (/home/runner/SayBot99109463/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:138:22)
    at Receiver._write (/home/runner/SayBot99109463/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:74:10)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:403:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:387:5)
    at Receiver.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:318:11)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (/home/runner/SayBot99109463/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:864:35)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
repl process died unexpectedly: exit status 1
```

Index.js:

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();


const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const cmd = require("node-cmd");
const ms = require("ms");
const fs = require('fs');
const ytdl = require("ytdl-core");
const canvas = require("canvas");
const convert = require("hh-mm-ss")
const fetchVideoInfo = require("youtube-info");
const simpleytapi = require('simple-youtube-api')
const util = require("util")
const gif = require("gif-search");
const jimp = require("jimp");
const guild = require('guild');
const hastebins = require('hastebin-gen');
const getYoutubeID = require('get-youtube-id');
const pretty = require("pretty-ms");
const moment = require('moment');
const request = require('request');
const dateFormat = require('dateformat');

app.listen(() => console.log("DwaCraft SayBot Starting...."));

const prefix = "*"//Prefix
const developers = ["612110791683866644","694996503324000378"] //Devs IDs
const dev1 = "612110791683866644"
const owner = "694996503324000378"
const dev3 = " "
const dev4 = " "


///help

      client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.content.toLowerCase() === prefix + "help") {
        message.delete(5000)
        if(!message.channel.guild) return;
        const e = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor('#36393e')
        .setTitle('sent in DM')
     const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
         .setColor('#36393e')
    
         .setDescription(`
         \`\`\`Main Commands  :\`\`\`         

         - ${prefix}ping : To know the connection speed of the bot
 
         \`\`\`Admin Commands :\`\`\` 
         
         - ${prefix}say : make the bot say any thing


`)
   message.channel.send(e).then(m => m.delete(5000))
   message.author.sendEmbed(embed).catch(error => message.reply('**open your dm to allow me to send it**'))
   
   }
   });
  
//say embad

client.on("message", message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

  let command = message.content.split(" ")[0];
  command = command.slice(prefix.length);

  let args = message.content.split(" ").slice(1);

  if (command === "say") {
    if (!message.channel.guild)
      return message.channel
        .send("This is only for servers")
        .then(m => m.delete(5000));
    if (!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR"))
      return message.channel.send("Unfortunately, you don't have the permission ADMINISTRATOR");
    message.delete();
    message.channel.sendMessage(args.join(" "));

    if (message == prefix + "say")
       message.channel.sendMessage("Please contain a message")
      .then(m => m.delete(3000));
  }
  if (command == "embed") {
    if (!message.channel.guild)
      return message.channel
        .send("This command is only for servers")
        .then(m => m.delete(5000));
    if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES"))
      return message.channel.send("You don't have the permission to use this command.");
    let say = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setDescription(args.join("  "))
      .setColor(694996);
    message.channel.sendEmbed(say);
    message.delete();
    
    if (message == prefix + "embed")
       message.channel.sendMessage("Please contain a message")
      .then(m => m.delete(3000));
  }
});
client.on("ready", () =>{
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
    client.user.setPresence({
        status: "online",  // Do not disturb is dnd
        game: {
            name: "DwaCraft.net",  // msg
            type: "PLAYING" // PLAYING, WATCHING LISTENING, STREAMING,
        }
    });
 });

 client.on("message", message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "setname")) {
    let args = message.content.split(" ");
    let botnameee = args.slice(1).join(" ");
    if (!developers.includes(message.author.id))
      return message.channel.send(
        `** :x: Only Developers/Owners Can Use this Command ! :x: **`
      );
    if (!botnameee)
      return message.channel.send(
       `** :x: Please Provide the new name ! :x: **`
      );
    message.channel.send(`Changing to the new Name...`).then(me => {
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      me.edit(`Changing to the new Name.`);
    }, 2000); //milliseconds, 1000ms = 1s
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      me.edit(`Changing to the new Name..`);
    }, 2000); //milliseconds, 1000ms = 1s
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      me.edit(`Changing to the new Name...`);
    }, 2000); //milliseconds, 1000ms = 1s
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      me.edit(`Please wait.`);
    }, 2000); //milliseconds, 1000ms = 1s
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      me.edit(`Please wait..`);
    }, 2000); //milliseconds, 1000ms = 1s
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      me.edit(`Please wait...`);
    }, 2000); //milliseconds, 1000ms = 1s
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      me.edit(`Done, Changed my name to *${botnameee}*!`);
      client.user.setUsername(`${botnameee}`);
    }, 12000); //milliseconds, 1000ms = 1s
    });
  }
  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "setavatar")) {
    let args = message.content.split(" ");
    let botnameee = args.slice(1).join(" ");
    if (!developers.includes(message.author.id))
      return message.channel.send(
        `** :x: Only Developers/Owners Can Use this Command ! :x: **`
      );
    if (!botnameee)
      return message.channel.send(
        `** :x: Please Provide an avatar ! :x: **`
      );
    message.channel.send(`Changing The bot's Avatar...`).then(me => {
   setTimeout(function(){ 
      me.edit(`Changing to the new Avatar.`);
    }, 2000); //milliseconds, 1000ms = 1s
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      me.edit(`Changing to the new Avatar..`);
    }, 2000); //milliseconds, 1000ms = 1s
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      me.edit(`Changing to the new Avatar...`);
    }, 2000); //milliseconds, 1000ms = 1s
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      me.edit(`Please wait.`);
    }, 2000); //milliseconds, 1000ms = 1s
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      me.edit(`Please wait..`);
    }, 2000); //milliseconds, 1000ms = 1s
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      me.edit(`Please wait...`);
    }, 2000); //milliseconds, 1000ms = 1s
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      me.edit(`Done, Changed Avatar to *${botnameee}*!`);
      client.user.setAvatar(`${botnameee}`);
    }, 12000); //milliseconds, 1000ms = 1s
    });
  }
});


client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

Note: I use https://replit.com hacker plan

You can talk to me at discord too Hamoodiyt#4822

If you need any more info ask me for it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1o9fW.png

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This helps you debug it on your own a bit first and narrow down the scope of where something might be breaking. Per the error message, a good place to start debugging would be `/home/runner/SayBot99109463/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/ClientDataManager.js` on line 81. The error message `Cannot read property 'id' of undefined` is basically saying `channel` is undefined.

Comment: I'm using Replit, I can't go in that file....

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1o9fW.png

Comment: Searching for "ClientDataManager.js Cannot read property 'id' of undefined" lead me to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66894757/discord-js-cannot-read-property-id-of-undefined?rq=1 which seems to be a duplicate question.

Comment: I Told you I can't get to that file..... which is why I asked......

Comment: Checkout this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67610078/guild-channels-setchannel-id-channel-cannot-read-property-id-of-undefined/67610079#67610079

Comment: Oh, Thanks now I  know what happened, thanks again !

Comment: I'd say dupe of [guild.channels.set(channel.id, channel) Cannot read property 'id' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67610078/guild-channels-setchannel-id-channel-cannot-read-property-id-of-undefined) as @Elitezen provided

Comment: Not really, but I'll delete anyway.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I could see, It seems that you're trying to access an attribute of an object that doesn't exist.

I think the property/attribute `message.author` is null.

Comment: But the bot was running on that for a while now, how wouldn't it exist?